# Is any minimum deposit required to receive eth in my wallet

Tags: transactions

I have got a massage in tweeter
" Sir for you to claim this offer you are required to have minimum of $50 on your digital wallet "
Is it a scammer  ??

Answer (score 1):

From the blockchain's perspective you don't need to have anything in your wallet in order to receive something there.

But external parties may have whatever requirements - be it a scam or not. So person A may tell person B that he agrees to send assets only if B has something in their wallet already. Don't ask me why.

Just be very careful with this kind of stuff. If it sounds too good to be true, it most likely is.